# Calling Rasterio resampling methods directly (or using an input shape for masks)

Tags: python, rasterio

I've been stuck trying to find a clean way to use a vector directly as a mask on a rasampled array. This code won't run because one mask is resampled and the other is in the raster's native resolution.

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.fill import fillnodata
from rasterio.mask import raster_geometry_mask
import numpy.ma as ma

downscale_factor = .5
with rasterio.open(input_path) as raster:
        if downscale_factor:
            out_shape = (int(raster.height * downscale_factor), int(raster.width * downscale_factor))
            transform = raster.transform * raster.transform.scale((raster.width / out_shape[1]), (raster.height / out_shape[0]))
        else:
            out_shape = raster.shape
            transform = raster.transform
        array = raster.read(1, out_shape=out_shape, resampling=Resampling.nearest, masked=True)
        mask = raster_geometry_mask(raster, country_mask.difference(lake_mask), invert=True)
        mask = mask[0] & ~ma.getmask(array)
array = fillnodata(array, max_search_distance=2, mask=mask, smoothing_iterations=2)
```

As far as I know there isn't any documented way of calling rasterio's resampling methods in the enums module directly. There also doesn't seem to be a way to specify an input shape when creating a mask from a vector. Is there a way of directly using rasterio's enums module to
make sure the two masks are resampled to the output size using the same algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Resampling`](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/rasterio/enums.py#L48) enum is just a group of named integer values. There's no methods to actually do any resampling in the enum.

You can use the resampled `out_shape` and `transform` to create your mask from your vector data using [`rasterio.features.geometry_mask`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.geometry_mask)

You would need to read in your vector data and access the geometry using geopandas or fiona.

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize there'd be other masking methods in the features module. That works. Thank you!